# EF 6 - Consume stored procedure and call ToListAsync()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to call a stored procedure via EF 6. Using ToList() works as expected and a list of entities is returned.  However, ToListAsync() does NOT seem to return data.  In sql Profiler, I can see the stored procedure being executed against the database.  However, the break point after the line for ToListAsync() does not get hit.  I never see data get returned.

code below

```
public async Task<List<MyEntityObject>> GetStoredProcedureData()        {

           List<MyEntityObject> MyEntityObjects;
           using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
           {
               var  MyEntityObjectsQry = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntityObject>("dbo.GetStoredProcedureData");
               MyEntityObjects =await MyEntityObjectsQry.ToListAsync();              
           }
           return MyEntityObjects;
       }
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] including the source code for `GetStoredProcedureData` stored proc and how the `GetStoredProcedureData` function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I was not consuming the method correctly.  I was using a windows service.  Plus, I could not add async to the Main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
     {    
         // async cannot be added to Main    
         // await  CallStoredProcedure(); will not work here
         Task<bool> task = Task.Run<bool>(async () => await CallStoredProcedure());
         var test = task.Result;
     }
```

```
static async Task<bool> CallStoredProcedure()
    {
        var dataService = new MyDataService();
        // just call my method with await
        var details = await dataService.GetStoredProcedureData();
        Console.WriteLine("found {0} items", details.Count);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The get method will be like

```
var myEntityObjectsQry = await dbContext.Database.ToListAsync();
```

More references here:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/async-query-and-save.aspx